# Ghostscript breakes TikZ shadows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, ghostscript, shadows

I use fancy TikZ shadows in my `pdflatex` document, it works fine. However, if I process the PDF document with ghostscript (or its `ps2pdf` frontend), the shadows get broken. The processing is aimed to reduce the size of the document because of many images, I recon it is an unrelated issue.

Here are the details. The MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
%% even fancier shadows
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
%% fade
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,node distance = 1.2em and 1.2em,  
  rounded corners=10, blur shadow={shadow blur steps=50}]
  
  \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, fill=blue!10, draw, text width=6em,
  text centered, minimum height=2.1\baselineskip,
  blur shadow={shadow blur steps=50}
  ]

  \node (t) [block] {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The original document after `latexmk -pdf mwe`:

[image: original file]

Now, I call `gs`:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.7  -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dColorImageResolution=72 -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dGrayImageResolution=72 -dMonoImageResolution=150 -dOptimize=true -q -o small-gs.pdf mwe.pdf
```

The result is:

[image: borked with gs]

I can also call `ps2pdf`: `ps2pdf mwe.pdf small-2pdf.pdf`, the result is the same. (No wonder, it's a frontend to `gs`.)

[image: broken with ps2pdf]

Versions:

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)
kpathsea version 6.3.2
Copyright 2020 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.02

$ gs --version
9.52
```

Verified on MacOS 10.15.6 and on a build system on GitLab (`texlive-latest`, Ubuntu image). I view the PDFs in Preview.app.

What am I doing wrong? (Aside from using Preview, obviously.)

How to retain a more wide compatibility of my PDF files?

Comment: Oka-aaaay, Chome's PDF viewer displays them just fine. This is a viewer problem, thus.

Comment: I have tried with Chrome's PDF viewer but I have the same result as with the other PDF viewers. I think that PGF/Tikz doesn't support transparency and fading (used by `shadows blur`) at all in the way tex->dvi->ps->pdf.

Comment: I produced the initial PDF with `pdflatex`, hence my suspicion it is a pure PDF issue.

Answer (score 6):

Support of Fadings (non-uniform transparency) for `dvips`+`ps2pdf` has been added to `pgf` very recently and is available only in its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf). For testing, download https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/archive/master.zip and copy the [`tex`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/tree/master/tex) folder therein into the working directory. Also, Ghostscript-9.52 is needed and `ps2pdf` must be run with option `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY`.

Comment: I am using `pdflatex` though. Is it still the issue of fadings in pgf then?

Comment: Yes, fading support for `dvips` is a recent addition to `pgf`.

Comment: Sorry, I seem not to get it. I use dvi **nowhere** in my pipeline. I produce PDF directly from LaTeX and then fiddle with the PDF with GS. I use ps2pdf as a front-end to to transform a PDF to a (hopefully smaller) PDF.

Comment: To reduce the size. 

 59M main.pdf
 13M test14-main.pdf

Comment: So I misunderstood you, sorry. I thought you were using the `dvips`+`ps2pdf` chain of commands in the hope to get a smaller PDF. But you used GS for postprocessing the PDF.

Comment: Yes, exactly this fully-PDF pipeline.

Comment: Maybe I was also a bit mislead by @F. Pantigny's comment. Apologies. Besides, I don't think that you may get a smaller PDF. With `dvips`+`ps2pdf` it is about 13k, with `pdflatex` 14k. (Which isn't excessive, I think.)

Comment: I have other parts in the actual production PDF, I want to make smaller. These parts are not in the MWE.

Comment: I should really make a new release soon, aiming for the end of September.  Thanks again for your extremely useful changes @AlexG!

Answer (score 1):

A lower PDF version helps, `ps2pdf13 mwe.pdf test-pdf13.pdf` functions as intended with rendering the shadows. The size is another issue...

[image: it works]

Comment: I tried with `ps2pdf13` and the current `pgf` 3.1.5b release, to no avail though. `ps2pdf13` doesn't make a difference here, you really need the Git version for fadings using `dvips`.

Comment: The drawback of PDF13 is that the whole page is saved as a bitmap.